# Help in simplifying this double summation

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, summation, closed-form

Can I express the following double summation

$$\sum_{(i,j)\in\mathcal{R}} A_{v_i} G(v_j-v_i)$$

where $\mathcal{R}=\{ (i,j) \in \mathbb{Z}^2,i \in [1:n], j \in [1:m]\}$ while $G(.)$ is any function of (.) and $A_{v_{i}}$ is any function of $v_{i}$ as

$$\sum_{i=1}^n A_{v_i} D_{v_i}$$

where $D_{v_i} = \sum_{j=1}^m  G(v_j-v_i)$.

Does anyone know if the simplification is right? I basically would like to have the expression in terms of $i$ only.

Can anyone think of another way?

Comment: Looks ok to me.

Comment: @ZachGershkoff thanks Zach